# Eclipse Juno: Unable to read model extension

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, e4

After exporting the product, when i try to run the application i do not see any view in my application.i got the reason, this is because of error "Unable to read model extension"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your product work fine when launched from within the Eclipse IDE? Only the exported product generates the error? Then check if the exported product indeed includes all the required files. For example, does it include the `plugin.xml`, `Application.e4xmi`, ...?

When launched from within the IDE, all source code files are available to the running product. When exported, however, only files specifically listed in the `build.properties` file of each plugin will part of the exported product. If for example the model files (*.e4xmi) are not listed in the `build.properties` file, your exported product will not be able to load the model.